# Saving Xbox Live profile picture

Tags: pc, xbox-network

Is there a way I can save the Xbox Live profile picture to a PC hard disk? I want to use it as my Gravatar.

Comment: Do you see your profile picture if you log into your Xbox Live account from a PC? It's been a while since I set mine up and as I'm at work I can't log on to check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go to xbox.com and login you should see your live profile picture displayed in the top right next to your name displayed in the top right-hand corner as seen below.

[image]

Depending on your browser, you can sometimes right click and save that image. Alternately, you can go to the following URL and find your profile picture:

http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/PROFILENAMEGOESHERE/avatarpic-l.png

You should place your profile name where it says PROFILENAMEGOESHERE. For example, you can find mine at:

http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/Doozer%20Blake/avatarpic-l.png

Some browser may replace any spaces or characters for you, but you may have to  replace any spaces in your username with a %20. You can also enter your name [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) and hit the Encode button to encode your username if it has any special characters in it.

Some other optional images you can grab for your avatar:

- a smaller version: 
  http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/PROFILENAMEGOESHERE/avatarpic-s.png
- a EXTRA LARGE version: 
  http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/PROFILENAMEGOESHERE/avatarpic-xl.png
- and a picture of your full avatar
  http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/PROFILENAMEGOESHERE/avatar-body.png