# Download Xbox 360 Profile Image

Tags: xbox-network

I have a profile picture for my Xbox Live profile that I would love to download. I got it for completing an achievement in Marathon: Durandal – I believe for the [VidMaster achievement](https://www.trueachievements.com/a17963/vidmaster-achievement) – and I have fond memories of getting the achievement. However, I have not been able to find a downloadable version of this image.

Unfortunately when I got my Xbox One I changed my profile picture, and I do not have the option to change it back (no Xbox 360 profile images were shown). This rules out [an answer to a similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11814/saving-xbox-live-profile-picture?newreg=709071e96ca445788d59072fde5ce6b4). The iOS app appears to allow images to be uploaded, so I would love to download the image from somewhere and upload it as my profile image.

[My profile on TrueAchievements](https://static.trueachievements.com/imagestore/0002624800/2624831.jpg) shows the image in WEBP form, but [changing the extension to .png yields a 64x64 png](https://static.trueachievements.com/imagestore/0002624800/2624831.png). I'm hoping that a higher resolution copy may exist on Microsoft servers!

My Xbox 360 profile still shows this image. I have tested this by loading a backwards compatible game on my Xbox One. So I'm hoping there's a URL somewhere that I can get this image from? I have tried a bunch of the "Xbox summary card" websites to see if they pull in my old profile image but so far none have.